# how can I fix the warning "Replace this union type with a type alias"

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, sonarlint

SonarLint gives the following and I have not found how to solve it since it is a global variable.

[variable sample img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl1K4.png)

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what the linter says. Create alias for union type.

```
type InformationType = 'someValue' | 'anotherValue';
// ....
informationType: InformationType;
```

Comment: understood it, when the variable is global, alias must be created outside the class, because inside class "type" cannot be used, only inside methods or outside the class.